# How to use bitset/read on 16bit numbers (Arduino)

Tags: programming, sketch

I'm working on an Arduino powered Tetris game. To keep track of the pieces that have fallen and become fixed I have an array of bytes

```
byte theGrid[] = {   
B00000000,
B00000000,  
B00000000,
B00000000,
B00000000,
...
```

This works great when the well is only 8 LEDs wide, but I need it to be 16 wide. Is there a way to perform bitwise operations on a 16 bit number, like a short? I tried just declaring theGrid as a short, but I'm getting this error no matter what I do.

```
tetris:62: error: 'B0000000000000000' was not declared in this scope
```

The reason I was using byte is so I could use bitread and bitset. So if an L piece comes down and lands, I can bitset the appropriate bits like this

```
bitSet(theGrid[pixelY], 15-pixelX);
```

and end up with

```
B1000000000000000, B1110000000000000
```

Comment: There are no bitwise operations in that code.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I edited the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem that you're having is that *binary literals don't exist in C*; the Arduino libraries get around this by having **every single binary value** from [1'b0](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/syntax1.html#Integer_Numbers) to 8'b1111_1111 defined as a macro in [`cores/arduino/binary.h`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/binary.h). The obvious workaround is to use octal, decimal, or hexadecimal literals instead.

```
unsigned short theGrid[] = {
00,
0,
0x0,
 ...
};
```

Bitwise operations work as normal.

```
theGrid[pixelY] |= _BV(15 - pixelX);
```

Comment: Thanks, I got a similar answer on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335115/how-to-perform-bitwise-operations-on-16bit-numbers-arduino). I think this will work :)